# How to save csv file in /public folder using laravel?

Tags: php, laravel

I am trying to save a csv file and download it. To download I used the following code.

```
$export = implode(",",$header)."\n";
foreach($data as $key=>$val)
{
     $export .= implode(",",$val)."\n";
}
header('Content-Type: application/csv');
header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename='.$filename);
echo $export;
exit();
```

The variables $header, $data and $filename can be different based on the program. However, this only takes care of the download portion. I want to save the csv file before downloading it. How can I do that?

Comment: you're making CSV file dynamic from database?

Comment: Not directly from database. Some data are being processed based on user's choice. And then CSV is being downloaded

Comment: use Laravel excel, reference [document](https://docs.laravel-excel.com/3.1/exports/collection.html#using-custom-structures)

Comment: I tried using laravel excel. However many of the file contents is in Japanese. Sometimes laravel excel can't process the encoding.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I didn't find any laravel specific solution. But I solved it using raw PHP.

```
$file = fopen($filename.'.csv','w'); //by default it uses public folder
fwrite($file,$export);
fclose($file);
```